# sql хочу получить min из counut

Tags: sql, min

задача такая. Есть две таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задача учебная, так что, чур, к названиям не придераться)

нужно получить из них название альбомов, содержащих наименьшее количество треков.

Я написал sql запрос

```
select count(s.song_id), a.album_title
from albums a 
join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id 
group by a.album_id;
```

и получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а, по идее, должно быть  все тоже самое без последнего пункта

уже всю голову сломал как сюда пристроить min()
помогите пожалуйста

1

```
select min(s.song_id), a.album_title
from albums a 
join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id 
where (count(s.song_id), a.album_title
from albums a 
join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id )
group by a.album_id;
```

2

```
select count(min(s.song_id)), a.album_title 
from albums a join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id
group by a.album_id;
```

3

```
select min( select count(s.song_id), a.album_title 
from albums a 
join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id
group by a.album_id);
```

Comment: сделайте это подзапросом, в основном запросе выберите строчки с минимальным count'ом

Comment: я совсем начинающий в sql так что простите не понимаю о чем вы

Comment: Тогда Вы явно не по адресу. Вам надо начать с чтения какого-нибудь учебника, чтобы владеть хотя бы минимальной терминологией. Какой смысл задавать вопрос, если не сможешь понять ответ?

Comment: изучить терминологию в процессе.
я делал подзапрос, но min(count()) нельзя применять т к недопускается вкладывать агрегатные функции

Comment: @Вова представьте, что у вас уже есть таблица, как то, что вы показываете, как результат. Вы знаете, как оттуда достать то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Можно делать запрос из результатов запроса. Только вам нужно будет как-то назвать поле count(s.song_id).

Comment: @splash58 нет, не знаю. Я уже кучу способов перепробовал ниче не работает!

Comment: А первый запрос вы сами написали или вам кто-то подсказал?

Comment: @splash58 сам написал

Comment: *Я уже кучу способов перепробовал* - Давайте, вы покажите некоторые из них, а мы вам подскажем

Comment: @splash58 
1
select count(min(s.song_id)), a.album_title
from albums a 
join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id 
group by a.album_id;

2
select min(
select count(s.song_id), a.album_title
from albums a 
join songs s on a.album_id = s.album_id 
group by a.album_id);

3

Comment: Добавляйте ваш код прямо в вопрос. В комментариях код не читабелен.

Comment: @Вова, вы знаете, что такое подзапрос?

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Comment: @splash да это подзапрос выполняется первым и его результаты передаются в основной запрос. Проблемки с синтаксисом)

Comment: https://learndb.ru/articles/article/87

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, но чет нифига не помогает. Я ему и так и сяк, а он мне или ошибку или не тот результат. Наверное, уже мозг отказывается воспринимать инфу. Буду признателен если напишите правильный код)

Comment: @Вова А какой у вас конкретно SQL? В разных версиях чуть по-разному может быть. Но всё же попробуйте почитать про подзапросы, там синтаксис вполне понятный. Сначала попробуйте без аггрегации, просто сделайте запрос одного поля, а потом из результатов этого запроса сделайте другой запрос. Так поймёте, как это должно выглядеть. Потом добавляйте элементы понемногу в подзапрос.